# How to handle batch size in custom loss function in tensorflow 2.3

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I'm trying to implement a custom loss function related to Triplet Loss. Triplet loss has a provision to give custom distance metric, that returns pairwise distances between embeddings. I have defined a custom function that works fine on forward-propagation. But on backpropagation it is throwing some error. Following is the error.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  slice index 16 of dimension 1 out of bounds.
 [[{{node TripletSemiHardLoss/PartitionedCall/while_1/body/_226/while_1/strided_slice}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_31232]
```

Function call stack:
train_function

16 is the batch size,my input had. I'm not using any while loop in the custom code. However, there is a for loop.

I have tried the following.

1. I retrieve the batch size using tf.size(input). Works fine on forward prop.
2. I have tried both while loop and for loop. On forward propagation, both are working fine. Both are producing same results. Yet on backprop, both are throwing the same error.

Here is the total error stack :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-70c4ddc79f73> in <module>
     11                            epochs=25,
     12                            callbacks=[checkpoint],
---> 13                            verbose=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    322               'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    323               instructions)
--> 324       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    325     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(
    326         func, new_func, 'deprecated',

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1827         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1828         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1829         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1830 
   1831   @deprecation.deprecated(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    838         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    839         # stateless function.
--> 840         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    841     else:
    842       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1846                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))],
   1847         captured_inputs=self.captured_inputs,
-> 1848         cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1849 
   1850   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1926         args,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    548               inputs=args,
    549               attrs=attrs,
--> 550               ctx=ctx)
    551         else:
    552           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  slice index 16 of dimension 1 out of bounds.
     [[{{node TripletSemiHardLoss/PartitionedCall/while_1/body/_226/while_1/strided_slice}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_31232]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: ok this is possibly because of a numpy style array slicing, I dd in the code. Perhaps, using  tf.slice will help.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was because of the numpy style array slicing. Using tf.slice resolved the issue.